# Error On Running Ruby Code named "No SDKs Specified"

Tags: ruby, rubymine

I have downloaded RubyMine IDE to run Ruby code. I have written the following code:

```
puts 'hello world'
```

But I have an error when I want to run this smallest program. The IDE shows the following error:

```
"No SDKs specified"
```

Why ? What to do if I want to solve this problem ? I am a beginner in this language. Can you guys help me in this regard ? Also, I want your suggestion: Is "RubyMine" the best IDE for Ruby ? What IDE do you use ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to configure the SDK here:

[image: Add SDK]

Use the <kbd>Add SDK...</kbd> button and specify the path to the ruby executable on your system.

On Windows you should install Ruby using http://rubyinstaller.org/ binary release. Not the source package.

---

Questions like `what is the best` or `your favorite` are not welcome on this site, [refer to the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: I want to know the name of IDE in where I can write Ruby code . Plz understand the theme of question and then come forward with your solution .

Comment: More specifically I want to know how can I remove the error faced by me in RubyMine IDE .

Comment: Forget about an IDE, while you're just starting out, work in console and  a "simple" text editor, like TextMate or Vim. IDE gets too much stuff out of your way, not helpful for learning the very basics. But RubyMine is the best IDE, yes

Comment: How can I perform this task ??
" specify the path to the ruby executable on your system" ?? What is the path name shown in "Ruby SDK" field ?

Comment: [Refer to help](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/configuring-available-ruby-interpreters.html), specify the path to `ruby.exe` or `ruby` binary if you are not using Windows. On my system this path is `d:\dev\Ruby19\bin\ruby.exe`.

Comment: In my ruby bin folder there are 6 files named "erb","gem","irb","rake","rdoc","ri","testrb" . Which one should I select ? I am using windows 8 .

Comment: Where did you get your Ruby distribution? What Ruby version do you use? There must be `ruby.exe` file in this directory, try to reinstall Ruby.

Comment: <URL:ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p0.tar.bz2>

Comment: I have downloaded it from ruby's oficial website

Comment: It's the source release, not the binary version for your OS, please use this site instead: http://rubyinstaller.org/.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25501/discussion-between-ocena-pothik-and-crazycoder)

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it like this (Idea 2019 Ultimate):

- File | Project structure | Modules
- select radio button on "Ruby SDK and Gems"
- Apply

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new project, you just need to configure the SDK also for run your project
[image: screenshot]